# structure Node js project via Express in ES6 and by using OOP concepts (classes etc)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Dear developers I need a help,
I want to create a RESTfull API in Node js and by using express. There is no problem to create it in ES5 by I have a lot of problems in ES6 because I want to use classes and other OOP concepts. I do not know how to structure it.
Suppose I have server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const api = new Api(router); //can you please say Can I have an Api class here which will determine routes;
```

In Api.js file I want to have something like this

```
class Api() {
  constructor(expressRouter) {
    this.app = expressRouter;
    this.determineRoutes();
}



determineRoutes() {
    this.app.get('/user', new User().create ); //Can you please note, can I have a User class here which will be a controller ????
    this.app.get('/profile', new Profile().create); //The same here

    }

}


//or at the end can I write something like this, create a singleton class ????
module.exports = new Api(router);
```

Comment: Why do you want a class here?

Comment: @JonasWilms I want to have everything in ES6 and structured by OOP concepts, in general I do not know what is the acceptable practice here (writing node api in es6), and if you know please share your practice

Comment: "Structuring by OOP concepts" only makes sense if what you're structuring is OO in nature. Unless you have a bunch of functionality across different `Api` classes, e.g., shared functionality, there's no point in shoehorning something that isn't OO into "OOP concepts". Will `Api` have subclasses? Is there anything involved other than setting routes? So far this is procedural in nature, and abstracting it out into OO doesn't gain you anything. When OOP is your hammer, everything looks like a thumb.

Comment: @DaveNewtonso what you will suggest in this case ?

Comment: Why not start with OOP in ES5? There's nothing changed in ES6 except for the syntax.

Comment: I totally agree with @DaveNewton. You won't have multiple `Api` instances, there's no need to use objects (and by far, no need to use classes) here. You already mentioned the singleton antipatern. The initialisation of your server is a totally simple procedural matter. If you want to learn about modularisation, break everything apart into functions and arrange them in ES6 modules.

Comment: @Bergi requirements are write it in ES6, but in general I agree with you, objects will not give me anything because I would have only one object of Api class, but if it is not a problem for you can you please answer me to one question, If I would write my project in ES6 and with classes how can I use controller classes in API router class ? create a new class every time when request is sent or create only one instance of that class and use it instead ?

Comment: "*requirements are write it in ES6*" - yeah, sure, but first need to get an idea what objects, constructors and prototypes you need. That hasn't changed from ES5, only the syntax to create them is different.

Comment: Regarding controllers, if you had route `/users/:id`, it might make sense to create a new `User` object from the id on each request. Still, the callbacks that you pass to express should be plain functions (at most, static class methods if they make sense inside an existing class).